How does the ISR (Interupt Service Routine) works in ESP-32, can we suspend or resume tasks inside the isr?
I getting issue in switching the tasks in using ISR (ESP-32).
Below is the code for the same.
struct Button {
  const uint8_t pin;
  volatile uint8_t numberKeyPresses;
};

# define buttonpin 15
# define ledpin 2
#define photopin 34
#define threshold 100
#define buffersize 16000
#define interval 1 //interval in milliseconds

TaskHandle_t(Rx1_handle);
TaskHandle_t(Rx2_handle);
TaskHandle_t(Tx_handle);

Button button1 = {buttonpin, 0};
volatile bool pressed = false;

void IRAM_ATTR isr() {
  static uint32_t lastPressTime = 0; // Store the last press time to debounce the button
  uint32_t currentTime = millis(); // Get the current time

  // Debounce logic to avoid multiple triggers in quick succession
  if (currentTime - lastPressTime > 400) {  // 200ms debounce time
    lastPressTime = currentTime;
    
    // Increment the press count (wrap around after 2 presses, for example)
    button1.numberKeyPresses = (button1.numberKeyPresses + 1) % 2;  // 2 total presses before wrapping around

    // Perform actions based on the number of presses
    switch (button1.numberKeyPresses) {
      case 0: // First press (or after 5 presses)

        vTaskResume(Rx1_handle);
        vTaskResume(Rx2_handle);
        vTaskSuspend(Tx_handle);

        // xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(Rx1, "Signal Recieving", 100000, NULL, 1, &Rx1_handle, 1);
        // xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(Rx2, "Signal Processing", 10000, NULL, 1, &Rx2_handle, 0);
        // vTaskDelete(Tx_handle);
        break;

      case 1: // Second press
        // Your custom logic for 2nd press, e.g., alternate functionality
        vTaskSuspend(Rx1_handle);
        vTaskSuspend(Rx2_handle);
        vTaskResume(Tx_handle);

        // vTaskDelete(Rx1_handle);
        // vTaskDelete(Rx2_handle);
        // xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(Tx, "Signal Transmitting", 10000, NULL, 1, &Tx_handle, 1);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }  
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);

  // Testing if LED is Working
  digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);

  pinMode(buttonpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(button1.pin, isr, RISING);

  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
    Rx1,         // Function to implement the task
    "Signal Recieving",       // Name of the task
    10000,           // Stack size in words
    NULL,            // Task input parameter
    1,               // Priority of the task
    &Rx1_handle,            // Task handle
    0               // Core where the task should run (Core 0)
  );

  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
    Rx2,         // Function to implement the task
    "Signal Recieving",       // Name of the task
    10000,           // Stack size in words
    NULL,            // Task input parameter
    1,               // Priority of the task
    &Rx2_handle,            // Task handle
    1                // Core where the task should run (Core 0)
  );

  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
    Tx,         // Function to implement the task
    "Signal Transmitting",       // Name of the task
    10000,           // Stack size in words
    NULL,            // Task input parameter
    1,               // Priority of the task
    &Tx_handle,            // Task handle
    1                // Core where the task should run (Core 0)
  );

  vTaskResume(Rx1_handle);
  vTaskResume(Rx2_handle);
  vTaskSuspend(Tx_handle);
}

String binData_rx = "";

char binaryToChar(String binary) {
  int value = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    value <<= 1;  // Shift left to make space for the next bit
    if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
      value = value | 1;  // Set the least significant bit if it's '1'
    }
  }
  return (char)value;  // Return the resulting character
}

void processData() {
  int indx = binData_rx.indexOf("00000010");
  // Serial.println(indx);
  binData_rx.remove(0, indx+8);
  while(binData_rx.length()) {
    String subData = binData_rx.substring(0, 8);
    binData_rx.remove(0, 8);
    if(subData == "00000011") break;
    char ch = binaryToChar(subData);
    // processedData += ch;
    Serial.print(ch);
    vTaskDelay(interval * 8 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); //in milliseconds
    // vTaskDelay(interval * 8 ); // in microseconds
  }
  binData_rx.clear();
  Serial.println("");
}

void Rx1(void *parameter) { // Recieves Signal
  Serial.println("Signal Recieving");
  for(;;) {
    int value = analogRead(photopin);
    if(value > threshold) binData_rx += '0';
    else binData_rx += '1';

    vTaskDelay(interval / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // in milli seconds
    // vTaskDelay(interval); // in micro seconds
  }
}

void Rx2(void *parameter) { // Processes the Signal
  Serial.println("Singal Processing");
  for(;;) {
    if(binData_rx.length() > buffersize) {
    binData_rx.remove(0, 15900);
    }
    else if(binData_rx.indexOf("00000010") > -1) {
      binData_rx.remove(0, binData_rx.indexOf("00000010"));
      vTaskDelay(interval * 10 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // in milli seconds
      // vTaskDelay(interval * 10); // in micro seconds

      processData();
    }

    vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // in milli seconds
    // vTaskDelay(500 * 1000); // in micro seconds
  }
}

// Tx part

String stringToBinary(String str) {
  String output = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    // Print the binary representation of each character
    for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
      
      output += String((c >> j) & 1);
    }
    // output += " ";
  }
  return output;
}

void Tx(void *parameter) {
  Serial.println("Signal Transmitting");
  for(;;) {
    if(Serial.available() > 0) {

      String input = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
      String binData_tx = "00000010"+stringToBinary(input)+"0000001100000011";
      //Serial.println(2);
      Serial.print( binData_tx);

      for(int i=0; i<binData_tx.length(); i++) {
        if(binData_tx.charAt(i) == '1') {
          digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
        
          //delayMicroseconds(interval);
        } 
        else {
          digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);
          //delayMicroseconds(interval);
        }

        // digitalWrite(ledPin, (binData[i] == '1') ? HIGH : LOW);
        delay(interval); // delay of 200ms
      }

      binData_tx.clear();
      Serial.println();

      digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {

}

I have been working on Li-Fi Communication Project. I am using ESP-32 for Tx and Rx end. The main issue arrising is that I have creaated multiple tasks and also I want that a single task should be active in both the cores.
I have created
task-1 : Signal Recieving
task-2 : Signal Processing
task-3 : Signal Transmitting
I want to use ISR to switch between these tasks such that at a time task-1 & task-2 are active and when the button is pressed only the task-3 is active and so on.

You're trying to control the scheduler directly by telling it which thread/task to activate when an event occurs. I would go about it another way.
The standard pattern in FreeRTOS (and many other RTOS-s) solves this using thread signaling tools. In short, your high-priority task (Tx in this case) is blocked, waiting on a thread communication object - e.g. an event group. When an interrupt occurs and its ISR wants to launch some processing, it signals the event group that your high-priority Tx task is waiting for. Assuming Tx has higher priority than other ready tasks, scheduler immediately switches to it when ISR exits.
// Create an event flag that signifies button press
const uint32_t EVENT_BUTTON = 0x01;
// Create an event group for task communication
EventGroupHandle_t g_evGroup;

void setup() {
  g_evGroup = xEventGroupCreate();
  // Create task Tx with higher priority than other tasks
  xTaskCreate(Tx, "Signal Transmitting", 10000, NULL, 2, &Tx_handle);
}

void IRAM_ATTR isr() {
  BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
  if (buttonPressed()) {
    // Signal event group to wake up task Tx
    if (xEventGroupSetBitsFromISR(g_evGroup, EVENT_BUTTON, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken)) {
      // See portYIELD_FROM_ISR() documentation for the details
      portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
    }
  }
}

void Tx(void *parameter) {
  while (true) {
    // Waiting for ISR to signal us
    xEventGroupWaitBits(g_evGroup, EVENT_BUTTON, pdTRUE, pdFALSE, portMAX_DELAY);
    // Do processing
  }
}


As reference material, I recommend their book Mastering the FreeRTOS Real Time Kernel - A Hands On Tutorial Guide.

You should never suspend (or delete) a task!
The only exception is when a task deletes itself (i.e. vTaskDelete(NULL)).
(A task suspending itself is pointless as it cannot be made free from race conditions, where direct-to-task notifications can do exactly the same thing while avoiding the synchronization issues "manual" suspending&resuming has.)
Stopping another task via suspend or delete is inherently unsafe because you cannot know in what state the task currently is.
Example: A task may normally acquire a lock, do some stuff, then release the lock again. If someone was to externally stop the task it may have just acquired the lock but never gets a chance to release it again, potentially leading to a chain of blocked tasks waiting for a task to finish which won't.
On an ESP32, tasks acquire and release some form of lock all the time, often without you even noticing. For instance, accesses to most hardware peripherals are guarded by the IDF drivers via locks to enable safe multi-tasking use.
Always use the (blocking) inter-task communication facilities FreeRTOS provides, i.e. direct-to-task notifications, semaphores, or queues.
